# Passing Class Objects as Arguments of Classes

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, game-development

I have been working on a tetris game and I have to pass an object into a function as its argument to use the object inside the function.

I made this function and it should be able to control the Board object from **Main.cpp** to update the coordinate.

```
void BlockInfo::send(Board board)
{
    for (int i = y; i < y + 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = x; j < x + 4; j++)
        {
            if (block[blockType][rotation][j][i])
            {
                board.setBoard(j, i, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
Board board;
while (true)
{
    Board board;

    BlockInfo blcInf;

    blcInf.send(board);

    board.draw();
}
```

This should have drawn a tetris block in the terminal but it didn't.

So I tried changing the send function to this:

```
void BlockInfo::send(Board board)
{
    board.setBoard(3, 3, true);
}
```

This should have drawn a single block at (3,3) in the console, but it didn't. Assuming that everything except this works properly (I checked and I am pretty sure), what is the problem here? If you think there are no problems in this part, what do you think might be the problem?

Comment: You should pass by reference (`Board& board`) instead of by value

Comment: Your issue is no different than this: `void foo(int x) { x = 10; }  int main() { int x = 0; foo(x); }` - You will see that the `x` in `main` is still 0, even after `foo` is called.  The rules of C++ doesn't change because your `Board` object is a class.  As mentioned, regardless of the type, you must pass a reference to see the results reflected back to the caller.

Comment: Also, if you are used to languages like Java or C#, where an object is treated differently when passed, well, C++ doesn't work this way.  If this is the case that you have used languages such as Java that does this automatically for objects, this is exactly why programmers who work in those languages initially stumble when writing C++ code, and can't figure out why their object, when passed, isn't being changed.

Comment: Usually I would have the bigger thing deal with the smaller thing. A `Board::setBlock(const BlockInfo &block, int x, int y, int rotation)` makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `void BlockInfo::send(Board board)` and `blcInf.send(board);` you always make a copy of `board` and inside `send` you modify that copy - but not the original `board` from `main`.

You need to pass the `Board` by reference, not by value.

With `void BlockInfo::send(Board& board)` you are not making a copy but a reference. So `send` is working directly on the passed `board` from `main` and you will see the change when you call `draw`.